# How do I say "boner"?

Tags: word-choice, slang

Its a term used in English to describe an erect penis. Thank you.

Comment: 一般的な用語が知りたいんですか？それとも俗語(slang)が知りたいんですか？

Comment: @chocolate please teach us the slang version of this word! Is it もっこり?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term is 勃起{ぼっき}. (The noun form at least)

Answer (score 4):

Sixty-odd years ago I learned the phrase "pull a boner" , meaning "make a stupid mistake", from American movies. This would be ミスをする (from English "mistake"), 失敗する or 間違える in Japanese. Probably best to try not to confuse the two senses of "boner". By the way,  勃起 is the formal term, corresponding to "erection"in English. I'm sure there must be a Japanese slang term, but don't know what it is.

Comment: Good guess man. http://dic.nicovideo.jp/t/a/%E5%8B%83%E8%B5%B7

Answer (score 2):

To add to paulb's post, the verb form (roughly, "to get a boner") is 勃起{ぼっき}する.